# I can't connect to servers because authentication servers are down

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Every time I connect to a premium server on my mac, it says that authentication servers are down. I asked my brother to join the same ip and he managed to get in. Me and my brother are on the same internet connection. I have no firewall. I tried doing the sudo nano /etc/hosts terminal but I see no lines mentioning "mojang".[image: firewall is off]

Comment: when you say "premium server" do you mean that you arent using a premium(aka paid for) account?

Comment: If you log in to a premium server with a non-premium account the error will be different (e.g. Invalid Session).

Comment: The error is also server-side, so it's probably a problem with the server.

Comment: @MrParrot but i dont think the auth servers r down forever, so that doesnt really make sense

Comment: check if you're able to join Hypixel, that is usually a good gauge of whether the problem is server-side or client-side

Answer (score 1):

This error comes when you are trying to join a premium server with a cracked account. I know this as I created a server and didn't set online mode to false, and then tried connecting to the server with a cracked account and it gave me the same error.
(online mode is present in the server.properties file which basically means that whether non-premium players can join the server or not)

If you are using a cracked account, then try joining a cracked serer like BlocksMc, and if this error comes upon joining a cracked server, then give a report to Mojang.

If you legally bought minecraft, then try joining other premium servers, if it works then that particular server may be having a problem, but if it doesn't work, then send a report to mojang.

I hope this helped you.